# How to use code under the Apache 2.0 license in an Unlicense-licensed project?

Tags: apache-2.0, unlicense

I'm the author of an open source project which is licensed under the Unlicense license. I want to modify an HTML file from another open source project that uses the Apache 2.0 license, and add the modified HTML file to my project.

I'm not sure if this behavior of mine is allowed. What should I pay attention to to achieve my purpose?

Comment: It is slightly misleading to think about this as an Unlicense-covered project that contains some Apache-covered parts. Instead, it is now a project containing both Unlicense- and Apache-covered parts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to include files under Apache license into your project under The Unlicense you should make it extra clear that this is a mixed situation.

- You must include all of the required information (copyright attribution, license language, ...) according to the Apache license in the header of the HTML file. The NOTICE and verbose license language can also be separate, but then at least you should have the copyright attribution and an SPDX identifier in the HTML file itself.
- It would be helpful to keep all the files related to the Apache licensed code in a separate subdirectory.
- The LICENSE file of your project should include a clear indicator, that there are files in this project under the Apache license (you could refer to the subdirectory with all the Apache-related files).